# Paypal IPN - Differentiating between Recurring Payment and Initial Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've created a recurring payments profile on Paypal setting an initial payment.

When I receive the IPN, the txn_id is the same for both the initial payment and the recurring payment. I would like to know if there's a way of differentiating between them.

I've noticed that when I receive the recurring payment, there's this variable "period_type= Regular". This doesn't appear in the initial payment IPN. Is this a good way to make the distinction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be getting confused with what you're getting in the IPN's.

When the profile is first created, you'll get an IPN with the profile ID of the profile that was just created, and you would only get a transaction ID if you included the original amount to be charged.  The transaction ID here is only for that original amount.  If you didn't have that all you would get is the profile ID.

If your recurring payments are scheduled to start on the same day as well you will get an additional IPN for the recurring payment and that will have its own transaction ID.